# Using Ansible postgresql_user with psycopg2 from VirtualEnv

Tags: postgresql, virtualenv, ansible

The Ansible postgresql_user module demands a working installation of psycopg2:

http://docs.ansible.com/postgresql_user_module.html

If this is installed in a VirtualEnv on the server, how can the Ansible module find it?

Other Ansible modules seem to have explicit VirtualEnv support, so is this simply a missing feature?

Comment: If you don't need it to be referring to the virtualenv then there are a bunch of options here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the psycopg2 module from the virtualenv, one possible solution would be

**Steps followed:**

1) Created a ubuntu 16.04 vagrant machine and installed postgresql.

2) Used the ansible postgresql_db module to create a new database and failed with error `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "the python psycopg2 module is required"}`

3) Create a virtualenv and install psycopg2 in virtualenv

```
virtualenv venv -p /usr/bin/python (Note: python2.7)
source venv/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```

4) Run ansible-playbook with **ansible_python_interpreter** to point to the python interpreter from the virtualenv and the database create task succeeded. The ansible command and contents are as follows,

```
---
- hosts: vagrant
  sudo: true

  pre_tasks:
     - raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
     - setup:

  tasks:
    - name: db create
      postgresql_db:
        name: acme
      become_user: postgres
```

The ansible-playbook command

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python"
```

Comment: Using the "ansible_python_interpreter" parameter is a great hint. Before accepting the answer: Wouldn't it make more sense to set it in the inventory configuration, as described here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html ?

Comment: @PeterTröger There are multiple ways to specify the ansible_python_interpreter variable, it depends on the user's preference I believe. If you want a persistent approach, you could set it in inventory or as an environment variable on a play level in the hosts section.